# $\frac{dz}{dt}=z'=-bz(1-az)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Differential equation

$\frac{dz}{dt}=z'=-bz(1-az)\implies z'+bz=abz^2$

My solution :

Define $v=z^{-1}$.

Then, $v'-bv=-ab$

Multiply both sides by integration factor $\mu$.

$(\mu \cdot v)=\mu' \cdot v + \mu \cdot v'=\mu\cdot v' - \mu bv \implies \frac {\mu'}{\mu}=-b \implies \int \frac {\mu'}{\mu} = -\int b$

$\implies \ln\mu=-bt \implies \mu=e^{-bt}$

Then we get $\mu=e^{-bt}$

$(e^{-bt}\cdot v'-b\cdot e^{-bt}\cdot v)=e^{-bt}\cdot ab \implies \int(e^{-bt}\cdot v'-e^{-bt}\cdot v)=\int(e^{-bt}\cdot ab) $

$\implies \int (ve^{-bt})'=\int e^{-bt}ab \implies v\cdot e^{-bt}=\frac{e^{-bt}\cdot ab}{-b}+C \implies v=-a+\frac{C}{e^{-bt}}$

The answer isn't correct , but I can't get what is wrong.

I'd be grateful for your help!

Comment: How did the last part begin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to do what you did.

You let $\mu=e^{-bt}$. So $\mu'=-b\mu$, then $a\mu'=-ab\mu=v'\mu-bv\mu=v'\mu+v\mu'$.

By integrating both side by $t$, $a\mu+C=\int a\mu'\text dt=\int(v\mu'+v\mu')\text dt=v\mu$.

So multiplying both side by $e^{bt}=\mu^{-1}$, we get $a+Ce^{bt}=v=z^{-1}$.

So, the answer is $z(t)=\frac1{a+Ce^{bt}}$.